# Express server not responding when CORS is enabled

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm studying NodeJS and Fullstack tecnologies. I'm following a webcourse, but differently from the teacher, I'm using a VM machine as the development server.

So I'm using Windows to use the browser to view the frontend and postman to manage the API and an Ubuntu VM, running all of the stack (NodeJS, React, Express, etc.)
Oh, the VM network is a brigde to my own, so it has it's own IP address in my network (192.168.x.xxx)

However, I'm facing CORS issues during the tests. On the backend, when the NodeJS CORS library is enabled, my backend doesn't respond any requests, but whenever it's disabled, it responds...

Example without CORS:

[image]

[image]

Example with CORS enabled:

[image]
[image]

It feels like I'm doing something wrong, but I've checked every possible error in the server. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure CORS properly, to do that just put this line:

```
const cors = require('cors');
//your declarations
app.use(cors());
//your code
```

Complete example from my code is:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();

app.use(cors()); <-- here call function
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') { app.use(logger('dev')); }

app.use(require('./server/index'));

module.exports = app;
```

Notice that, in my code in the line I invoke `cors` I'm calling a function (with parenthesis).

Comment: I've actually done that on my example with cors enabled.

Comment: instead of app, i've declared express as "server"

Comment: In your app, you used a different , you did: `server.use(cors)`

Comment: you have to call the function with parenthesis.

Comment: Half a day struggling with this very issue. Blind me did not see the missing (). Thanks @Danzavtz!! How can I be so…:)